# ionic cap iOS info.plist issue

Tags: ionic-framework

I still get those warn but I think I put all as need... I try to add to my info.pllist to make Facebook login and google login work in my ionic 6 with cap.

please try to help me to fix it I don't find any solution why I keep get those warn..

those the errors I get after sync cap:

```
    [capacitor] [warn] Configuration might be missing for cordova-plugin-facebook-connect.
[capacitor]        Add the following to the existing CFBundleURLTypes entry of Info.plist:
[capacitor]        
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
[capacitor]        <array>
[capacitor]        <string>fb$APP_IDFACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME_SUFFIX_PLACEHOLDER</string>
[capacitor]        <string>OTHER_APP_SCHEMES_PLACEHOLDER</string>
[capacitor]        </array>
[capacitor]        </dict>
[capacitor]        
[capacitor] [warn] Configuration might be missing for cordova-plugin-googleplus.
[capacitor]        Add the following to the existing CFBundleURLTypes entry of Info.plist:
[capacitor]        
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
[capacitor]        <string>Editor</string>
[capacitor]        <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
[capacitor]        <array>
[capacitor]        <string>$REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
[capacitor]        </array>
[capacitor]        </dict>
[capacitor]        
[capacitor] [warn] Configuration might be missing for cordova-plugin-facebook-connect.
[capacitor]        Add the following to the existing NSAppTransportSecurity entry of Info.plist:
[capacitor]        
[capacitor]        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>facebook.com</key>
[capacitor]        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
[capacitor]        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
[capacitor]        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
[capacitor]        <true/>
[capacitor]        <false/>
[capacitor]        </dict>
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
[capacitor]        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
[capacitor]        <true/>
[capacitor]        <false/>
[capacitor]        </dict>
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
[capacitor]        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
[capacitor]        <true/>
[capacitor]        <false/>
[capacitor]        </dict>
[capacitor]        </dict>
```

this my info.pllst file (all if him):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>myappname</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Role</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
                <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                 <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
            </dict>
                    <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>fb$APP_IDFACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME_SUFFIX_PLACEHOLDER</string>
                        <string>OTHER_APP_SCHEMES_PLACEHOLDER</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix</key>
    <string>FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME_SUFFIX_PLACEHOLDER</string>
    <key>FacebookHybridAppEvents</key>
    <string>$FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires photo library access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires calendar access to function properly.</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>$APP_NAME</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
    <key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires motion detection access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires Bluetooth access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires microphone access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires camera access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
    <key>FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled_PLACEHOLDER</key>
    <string>FACEBOOK_AUTO_LOG_APP_EVENTS_PLACEHOLDER</string>
    <key>FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled_PLACEHOLDER</key>
    <string>FACEBOOK_ADVERTISER_ID_COLLECTION_PLACEHOLDER</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>$APP_ID</string>
    <key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires reminders access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
        <string>citymapper</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>navigon</string>
        <string>transit</string>
        <string>waze</string>
        <string>yandexnavi</string>
        <string>uber</string>
        <string>tomtomhome</string>
        <string>com.sygic.aura</string>
        <string>here-route</string>
        <string>moovit</string>
        <string>lyft</string>
        <string>mapsme</string>
        <string>cabify</string>
        <string>baidumap</string>
        <string>taxis99</string>
        <string>iosamap</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires constant Bluetooth access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Capacitor, you need to make some changes that are not documented (yet). If you only need the login, you are better off with the [@capacitor-community/facebook-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/facebook-login) plugin.

You can safely ignore the log-noise from the plugin after you set-up your info-plist correctly.
If you need it to get it work, Here's an example .plist for facebook:

```
        <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb<blabla></string>
        </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.blabla-blabla</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
```

[...]

```
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>blababa</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>blababa</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>blababa</string>
    <key>FacebookHybridAppEvents</key>
    <string>"true"</string>
    <key>FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```

You should also modify you AppDelegate.swift on iOS i.e.

```swift
    import UIKit
    import Capacitor
    import FBSDKCoreKit
    
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
      var window: UIWindow?
    
    
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
          FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
          application,
          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        return true
      }
    
      func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
      }
    
      func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
      }
    
      func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
      }
    
      func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
      }
    
      func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
      }
    
      func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        // Called when the app was launched with a url. Feel free to add additional processing here,
        // but if you want the App API to support tracking app url opens, make sure to keep this call
        if (FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
          app,
          open: url,
          sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )) {
          return true;
        } else {
            return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
          }
        }
      
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        // Called when the app was launched with an activity, including Universal Links.
        // Feel free to add additional processing here, but if you want the App API to support
        // tracking app url opens, make sure to keep this call
        return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
      }
    
    
    
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .capacitorDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications, object: deviceToken)
      }
    
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .capacitorDidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications, object: error)
      }
    
    
    }
```